# How to send and receive hidden value using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, hidden

This is my job id which is in php.

```
<td id="JobId"><?php echo $JobResults['id_job']; ?></td>
```

This is my reinvite button when i clicks this button i have to send hidden value that is job id using ajax:

```
<button id="ReInvite">Reinvite</button>
```

And this my ajax call:

```
$('#ReInvite').click(function() {
    JobId = $('#JobId').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "job-controller.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {'action':'reinvite','JobId' : + JobId},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                $("#showMessage").html(response['message']);
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            $("#showMessage").html("OOPS! Something Went Wrong Please Try After Sometime!");
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

this is my controller page to call the hidden value:

```
if($_POST['action']=='reinvite'){ 
    $Jobid = trim($_GET['JobId']);
    echo $JobId;
    exit;
});
```

My Error is job id value is coming as zero.

Comment: Change your `data: {'action':'reinvite','JobId' : + JobId},` as `data: {'action':'reinvite','JobId' : + $('#JobId').html()},` and try

Comment: @DavidR it worked thank you.

Comment: Did you declare JobId var ?

Comment: You are using JobId = $('#JobId').val(); to retrive job id but in your html you have <td> that hold JobId value you should use .text() instead on .val() because there is no method .val() for a <td> element

Comment: @AbdulWaheed Okay!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to change your,

```
data: {'action':'reinvite','JobId' : + JobId},
```

as,

```
{'action':'reinvite','JobId' : + $('#JobId').text()},
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 6):

Change this line:

```
JobId = $('#JobId').val();
```

to:

```
JobId = $('#JobId').text();
```

`val()`in jQuery is used to pull data from textareas and inputs. You can use `text()` to extract text from html elements, or `html()` to extract the entire html within that particular element.

Answer (score 3):

It should be `$_POST['JobId']` not `$_GET['JobId']`

Answer (score 2):

You must get it from the $_POST not the $_GET.